# PHP Google API client not getting access token (getAccessToken)

Tags: php, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to just create a connection to the Google YouTube API using the sample scripts Google provides:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads

The script I'm using is upload video.

I've created OAuth2 credentials (client ID and secret key) and these I've put into the sample script:

```
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'MY CLIENT ID';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'MY CLIENT SECRET';
```

Note: these are just example, not my real credentials :) But just to demonstrate that I'm copying the correct credentials to the correct variables.

I've double checked that these are correct. But when I try to get the access token, it returns NULL:

```
var_dump($client->getAccessToken()); exit;
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
.
.
.
```

I'm a little new to Google API so I wanted to start with the sample scripts, but not sure how where to go from here. I feel I've followed exactly as instructed. Any ideas? Thanks

===

Below is the full script up until I exit. I did make some minor changes (show errors, load library with composer - v2.0.0-RC4) but shouldn't really make much difference to the script:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
//require_once 'Google/Client.php';
//require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'MY CLIENT ID';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'MY CLIENT SECRET';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');

$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
//$redirect = '';

$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
var_dump($client->getAccessToken()); exit;
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
.
.
.
```

Comment: Did you manage to get it figured out? If so how?

Comment: Hi. Sorry I can't recall what the solution (if any) was to this. I don't have access to the code anymore coz it was a previous company. If you do come across a solution, please add it here. Probably something I should have done, sorry. Good luck anyway!